# php copy image from array url

Tags: php, arrays, image, curl

I'm trying to copy images from an array of URLs with the following code. The problem is it only saves the last picture, anyone knows why is this?

```
foreach($photos['data'] as $photo)
{
    echo "guardando:";
    echo $photo['id']; 
    $idFoto++;
    $fp = fopen('foto'.$idFoto.'.jpg', 'wb');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $photo['source']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
    curl_setopt($conn[$i], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Comment: `$idFoto` is declared outside the foreach ?

Comment: without knowing what's in the `$photos` array, we can't really help you. but why `$ch` and `$conn[$i]` for your curl_setopts handles? you can't mix handles like that in a single request.

Comment: Can you share the array? It seems you're not iterating through properly.

Comment: Yes it is declared aoutside the forEach,

Comment: WHat i got in my array is an array of urls (facebook urls)

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is in `curl_close($ch)`, this call should be outside for bucle or maybe you could call `curl_init` for each photo also could check if `curl_setopt` is returning true or false:

```
foreach($photos['data'] as $photo)
{
    echo "Guardando $idFoto: $photo['source']\n";
    $idFoto++;
    $fp = fopen('foto'.$idFoto.'.jpg', 'wb');
    $ch=curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $photo['source']);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    if(curl_exec($ch)===false) echo "Error: ".curl_error()."\n";
    fclose($fp);
    curl_close($ch);
 }
```

Also note `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` is not needed because we are saving to file and not assigning `curl_exec` return. Could you test please?

Comment: Hey zeroWorks well actuaylly I also tried with the cour_close outside, and i gat the same problem...

Comment: Try the code, geting the same problem, is curious i get a list of url with images from facebook, sometimes it saves 3 of 10 pics, sometimes only 1, but always the same images are saving... 
I do get the error from the curl_exec($ch)===false)

Comment: Could you test, and tell us which error appears when `curl_exec` fails?